# Excel - copying specific non-blank cells from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have a question about copying specific non-blank cells from one Excel sheet to another. I would normally use the INDEX/ROW but in this case I need to choose 1 from 3 cells, depending if a person is working normal hours, overtime, or swap shift and copy those hours in specific format to another sheet. I thought it might be easier to do it with VBA.

Below is a specific example:

Sheet 1
On Sunday 27/12/20 EMPLOYEE 1 will work 12.00hrs FLAT (BH14) and I need to copy this information to Sheet2 (I17).

The next day Monday 28/12/20 EMPLOYEE 1 will work 12.00hrs SWAP shift (different column this time - BJ74) and I need this to feed into Sheet2 (J17).

On Tuesday 29/12/20 EMPLOYEE 1 will work 10.00hrs OVERTIME shift (column BI134) and I need this to feed into Sheet2 (K17).

It is important that the hours that are being copied into Sheet2 stay in the same format - so either normal (for FLAT), purple (for SWAP), or blue (for OVERTIME).

Comment: Use an if statement to check if Flat is empty, then check Swap, then Overtime. Grab whichever has a value and paste with formatting.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. In 'Sheet2' I would need to do that for each cell, for each employee, for the whole year. Wouldn't it super slow down the whole spreadsheet?

Comment: An If statement is going to be super fast, like an increase of a few milliseconds across hundreds of thousands of rows. If you are seeing a noticeable slow down then something else is bottle-necking you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the problem here. Is it about making a decision about what kind of shift is it? How to decide what copy to where?

Regarding copying specific format you can try

1:

```
Sheet1.Range(BH14).Copy
Sheet2.Range(I17).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

2:

```
Sheet2.Range(I17).Value = Sheet1.Range(BH14).Value 'You will copy value this way    Sheet1.Range(BH14).Copy 'copy the formatting (like colors)
Sheet2.Range(I17).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats 'paste the formatting <br>
Application.CutCopyMode = False   'clear memory
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The value should be copied to the 'Sheet2' no matter what, or stay blank if the person has no value in 'Sheet1' for the day. The most important part is, that in 'Sheet2' I still need to be able to differentiate between normal shift, overtime and swap shift. I have that based on the conditional formatting and the hours then feed into my daily total - so if person 1 works 12 hrs overtime and person 2 also does, I will have 24 hrs in overtime for that particular day - that's why the formatting is so important.

Comment: The 'Sheet1' is like a daily "task" planner and based on that I get my total hours in the overview part (yearly labour planner) which is 'Sheet2'. Not sure if that makes sense?

Comment: Hey,
solution 2 should copy the condition formatting as well.
Could you put this excel on some google drive?